# How do I hide my banner ad from Google Mobile Ads in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ads

I need to create an ad on my game which I do successfully without issue but the second I want to remove it the issues start appering from left and right. I am attempting to create a function which is called BannerHide() and then i have linked it to a button, so when the user clicks play the button is linked to this function which should then hide the ad.

I have tested this and it is still not working.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdsScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public BannerView bannerView;

    void Start ()
    {
        RequestBanner();

    }

    public void RequestBanner()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
       string adUnitId = "ADID";
#else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

        // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
        BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
         .AddTestDevice(AdRequest.TestDeviceSimulator)       // Simulator.
         .AddTestDevice("MYDEVICEID")  // test device.
         .Build();

        // Load the banner with the request.
        bannerView.LoadAd(request);


    }

    public void BannerHide()
    {
        bannerView.Hide();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? Put `Debug.Log` inside the `BannerHide` function and see if that's even being called.

Comment: I just did i am getting the error object reference not set to an instance of an object. I have never done ads before code help is what i need, what am i missing to make this work

Answer (score 1):

The `bannerView` reference in your `BannerHide` method is `Null`, therefore you get an error.
To fix the error, in your `RequestBanner` method, replace:

This line `BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);`

With this line `bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);`

Comment: Ahh... scope...